# Copy rows from table on sheet to the end of a table on a separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I’ve been researching for days not finding the VBA for doing this. I want to take rows that are on tables on other sheets and paste them into 1 table in 1 sheet at the bottom.

Example:
Sheet 1 has a table “table1”. 
Sheet 2 has a table with data “table2”
Sheet 3 has a table with data “table3”

I want to take the data (entire table without headers), copy and paste that into “table1” on sheet1 at the end of the table. Then I will copy and paste the code for sheet3 and others. I’m stumped getting this to work for 1 sheet let alone multiple. Thanks!

Comment: Please start with the macro recorder. That should get you at least a base to begin from.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming all of your sheets 1 through 3 are in the same workbook. If not change `ThisWorkbook` to point to whatever workbooks the sheets '2' and '3' are in. I also assume that your tables are all the same size.

```
Sub CopyTablesToTable1()
    ' Assign worksheets
    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim sheet3 As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set sheet1 = .Worksheets("Sheet 1")
        Set sheet2 = .Worksheets("Sheet 2")
        Set sheet3 = .Worksheets("Sheet 3")
    End With

    'Get the table to copy to
    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Set targetTable = sheet1.ListObjects("table1")

    If Not targetTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then _
        targetTable.DataBodyRange.Delete '' clear out table 1 data and rows

    Dim srcData As ListObject
    Dim targetRange As Range


    ' Get the first Source Table Copied
    Set srcData = sheet2.ListObjects("table2")
    Call CopyTableData(targetTable, srcData)

    '' Copy the second source table copied
    Set srcData = sheet3.ListObjects("table3")
    Call CopyTableData(targetTable, srcData)


End Sub

Sub CopyTableData(targetTable As ListObject, srcData As ListObject)

    '' If the target table already has data
    If Not targetTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        '' top left part of the range
        '' targetTable.DataBodyRange.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

        '' Bottom Right part of the range
        '' targetTable.DataBodyRange.End(xlDown).Offset(srcData.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, srcData.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 1)
        Set targetRange = Range(targetTable.DataBodyRange.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0), _
                                targetTable.DataBodyRange.End(xlDown).Offset(srcData.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, srcData.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 1))

    Else '' If the target table is empty

        '' top left part of target
        ''targetTable.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1,1).offset(1,0)

        '' Bottom right part of the target range
        '' targetTable.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(srcData.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, srcData.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 1)

        Set targetRange = Range(targetTable.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0), _
                                targetTable.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(srcData.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, srcData.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 1))

    End If

    ' Copy the data
    targetRange.Value = srcData.DataBodyRange.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! What would the code look like if I want the table on sheet 1 cleared out first then the data copied from sheets 2 and 3 and placed on sheet 1 in starting in the first row of the table?

Comment: @butterflies2003 I have updated the code to clear out the table and wrote a separate sub to handle copying data to the target table whether the target table has data in it or not. Give that a whirl! :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! This has made work I have been trying to do for days work and so much easier! Thank you!

Comment: I added new columns to  sheets 1-3 (the same columns and want it to work with that but I keep getting an error. "Object variable or With block variable not set". When I click debug it points to the set targetRange = Range (targetTable.DataBodyRange.End(xlDown).Offset (1,0),_  targetTable.DataBodyRange.End(xlDown).Offset(srcData.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, srcData.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count-1))

Comment: Are tables 2 & 3 either empty? The code does assume that there is data in both tables. If not can you screenshot the tables you have to give me a better idea of what we are dealing with?